# DriveApp.getFileById(fileId) - Error: No item with the given ID could be found

Tags: google-apps-script

The following line of code:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
```

sometimes produces the error message:

- No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have
  not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.

Background information:

- The Google Apps Script tries to access a Google Slide document
- The document is owned by me, the sharing setting is "Anyone on the Internet with this link can edit"
- The script is used by ~100 users, all of them can access the document via the script, except one user

What I have investigated so far:

- The specific user seems to be a G Suite / Google Workspace user
- There seems to be no settings within "Google Admin" console to disable the ability for users to access shared Google documents - at least I did not find it
- It seems to be no single incident, because the same user produced the same error message on a couple of days

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you explicitly share the file with this user? Are they on your domain or another domain?

Comment: Good idea. This message was displayed: Sorry, the administrators of XXX do not allow items from YYY to be shared with users in their domain. Thank you, now I know the cause for this issue :)